# How can I Using jquery TOOLS validation for a form, dictate the position of an error message

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, jquery-tools

I am new to both SO and web development in general. Sorry for my general ignorance.

I have built a form which has validation ahead of form submission. 
I have included jqueryTOOLS basic validator: http://www.jquerytools.org/demos/validator/index.html

It works fine, but I need to adjust the position of the error message, which I have discovered I can do with the following code:

```
$("#myform").validator({
position: 'center left',
offset: [-2, 80],
});
```

However, it is adjusting the position of the LEFT hand side of the div containing the error message. Because I would like the error to appear on the LEFT of each field, I am trying to anchor the RIGHT hand side of the error message, not the left.

So while I can move the error messages around using the position and offset, I want the point of the error message I am moving around to change.

This is important because the error messages are of different lengths, and so if I anchor the left side, then longer messages will cover the fields that require interaction.

I hope this was clear, I can explain more if not! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the jquery tools plugin setting the `left` css attribute vs. the `right`  attribute. It's absolutely positioned on the page so the calculation it does for 'center left' is incorrect.. it should be calculating distance from right side of page, not left. You can even see this failure on their [demo page](http://www.jquerytools.org/demos/validator/index.htm): just open up a console and run this:

```
$("#myform").validator({position:'center left', offset:[0,0]})
```

Click submit and you will see it doesn't work

You could force a certain width for the error width (e.g. 200) and then you could pass in offset:[0,200] and it will appear correctly.

Otherwise you'll probably have to manually fix the logic in the plugin source (and submit a bug to them!)

Comment: Many thanks - a clear response! Manuarlly fixing the logic of the source is beyond me at the moment I'm afriad, I'll try the forced width - my one thought on that though is that given the background of the error msg is a solid colour, won't I result in a span of solid colour going right the way from the right hand side of the page? Perhaps I misunderstand

Comment: Not if you set it to something reasonable like 200px. It will butt up against the input box and go left from there 200px. Not sure of your layout but that's my best guess that would fit